# How to add a basic jQuery table

Tags: jquery, html

How do I add a simple table (2 columns, 10 rows) into a section of a page. It has 10 rows because there will be 10 entries that will be dynamic (changed upon manual refresh) that come from the back-end DB. (Irrelevant but the second column will be a bit.ly address to the entry, per each entry)?

Sorry if this sounds terribly stupid, but I have no idea how to design.

The reason I asked for a jQuery plug-in is because it'll look way better than an html table. Instructions on how to put *all* jQuery code into the html page will be appreciated.

Comment: jquery doesn't make things look better...?

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking for some nice looking CSS templates instead?

Comment: Depending on where you want to insert the data, you can simply use .append() or .prepend() or .before() or .after().

http://api.jquery.com/append/ | http://api.jquery.com/prepend/ | http://api.jquery.com/before/ | http://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to style the table?  Here are some CSS examples. http://robertdenton.org/reference/css-tables-tutorial.html

jQuery itself doesn't handle styles.

Comment: Although it can with .css() or .addClass() or .removeClass() if you need to do CSS changes on the fly.